# Conditional Redirect on props status

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect the page if the length of props.fields is zero. But the problem it is getting rendered twice so when the it is empty it gets redirected and doesn't wait for the second time.
I am new to React, it would be great if someone could help me.I have spent hours on fixing this.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Field from './field'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'





export default function FieldList(props) {

    const [redirect,setRedirect] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.fields.length===0) {
            setRedirect(true)
        }
        else
            setRedirect(false)
    },[props.fields])
    
         return (
                <div>
                <h1 style={{textAlign:"center", margin:"20px 0"}}>{props.text}</h1>
                
                <div className='field-list'>
                {props.fields.map((name) => (
                    <Field name={name}  />
                ))}
                </div>
                {redirect && <Redirect to={'/'} />}
            </div>
            )
        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can instead of `Redirect` either use a custom browser history or use `react-router-dom`'s useHistory hook

to use `useHistory` hook

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and then at the`useEffect`

```
   useEffect(()=>{
       if(props.fields.length===0) {
        useHistory().push('/')
        }
      },[props?.fields]
    )
```

if you don't want to use that, here is what you can do to create a custom browser history

first create a file and call it History.js

add this line of code to it

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

and then import it to the file

```
  import history from "FILE_PATH"

   useEffect(()=>{
       if(props.fields.length===0) {
        history.push('/')
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: when i go to that route now, I have to reload it again for it to re render it

Comment: tried it already, same issue, the route changes before mounting

Comment: you want to change the route if field inputs is equal to null take some seconds then go back to main route, right?

Comment: yes basically check if the props.field is not empty if it is just go back

Comment: it doesn't re render it again, I have to refresh it for it to work

Comment: did you wait for 3 seconds? if so try to remove the array dependency

Comment: not working it changes the route but it doesn't renders the component assigned to the router, moreover it also changes the route when fields is not empty

Comment: Then you can create a sandbox example. Without that i can't help further. Although  this is a bad way to do that, think about it you're changing the route and if field was empty you change it back. Instead you should not change rout if it is empty

Answer (score 0):

You should change your jsx to

```
            <div>
                <h1 style={{textAlign:"center", margin:"20px 0"}}>{props.text}</h1>
                
                <div className='field-list'>
                {props.fields.map((name) => (
                    <Field name={name}  />
                ))}
                </div>
                {redirect ? <Redirect to={'/'} /> : null}
            </div>
```

Comment: now when the fields is not empty, its still going back to index route